# Inserting ID from primary col to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert 2 tables columns ids to another table
I got the query but there is the annoying error.

I tried to solve this problem for hours none worked :(

This code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO
    groups(
      group_school_id,
      group_teacher_id,
      group_name,
      group_note,
      group_system,
      group_students_count
    )
  VALUES(
      $group_shcool_id,
      $group_teacher_id,
      '$group_name',
      '$group_note',
      '$group_system',
      '$group_students_count'
    )";
```

this old:

```
<?php

$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "admin";
$db['db_pass'] = "1998";
$db['db_name'] = "ahlquran";

foreach ($db as $key => $value) {
    define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}
?>
```

this new:

```
<?php

// if you are using php just don't forget to add php tags though

$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "admin";
$db['db_pass'] = "1998";
$db['db_name'] = "ahlquran";

foreach ($db as $key => $value) {
    define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}

//using try catch statements  
try{
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Successfully Connected";
}
catch(PDOException $e){
  echo "Connection Failed" .$e->getMessage();
}

?>

its connects successfully but all my code use the old one, how to change to convert it? I dont know what pdo I like to learn it, it seems more pro type, but is there solution for this site only using mysqli?

sorry for the long post this is my 1st one, dont know how to explain enough

Thanks
```

give this error :

> QUERY FAILED .You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , 'test', '', 'test' at line 11

I thought it will work fine like this but I think the problem with the query syntax.

Comment: `echo $query;`, what does that output?

Comment: $group_shcool_id you spelled school wrong here, so you’re not supplying a value for that column. If this were a varchar column with quotes, it would just insert an empty string, but since it’s an integer, it’s a syntax error.

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Munging query strings with parameter values is gong to lead to hard-to-debug syntax errors and SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @BenderBoy the school id var corrected still error

Comment: @Qirel How to echo it? it does not output in ```echo $query;```, sorry i am new to this.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I am still learning, i am new , can u give src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an advice try to use PDO prepared statements example below:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO groups(group_school_id,
                group_teacher_id,
                group_name,
                group_note,
                group_system,
                group_students_count) 
    VALUES (:gsid,:gtid,:gname,:gnote,:gsystem,:gstudcount)";


//assuming  $conn is your object variable name for database connection

$stmnt = $conn->prepare($query);

$stmnt->execute(array(':gsid'=>$group_school_id,
                      ':gtid'=>$group_teacher_id,
                      ':gname'=>$group_name,
                      ':gnote'=>$group_note,
                      ':gsystem'=>$group_system,
                      ':gstudcount'=>$group_students_count));
    //to check if you have inserted data into your table
    $rows = $stmnt->rowCount();
    echo "Inserted ".$rows." row";
```

the :gsid are placeholders for your variables, also make sure that each variable passed are inline with column datatypes in your database

```
//if you are using php just don't forget to add php tags though

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "whatevername";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

//using try catch statements  
try{
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Successfully Connected";
}
catch(PDOException $e){
  echo "Connection Failed" .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: the code seems very clean, but how to execute it? I use something like ```$create_group = mysqli_query($con, $query);```

Comment: added some codes, for PDO connection to your database, better create a separate file for it so you can use it anytime just by including it into other files assuming you use PHP?

Comment: the execution is on the line $stmnt->execute

Comment: honestly I am new to PDO (what is it?) I will post my db_config.php

Comment: here is the URL for PDO manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php, its pretty handy once you get used to it,it will also answer most of your questions or you could visit some sites that has actual examples like www.w3schools.com

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to make it workm sorry to trouble you

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, Is there MySQLi Solution? I am having trouble with PDO, Sorry again :(